# Angular and http.get - limit results by a variable condition

Tags: angular

I have a component in my Angular application that needs to display one item from a file containing an array of json objects that depends on the id (which can change).  To accomplish this, I have a service that can read in the json file.  That process works, but I need to be able to limit the response to just the item that has the corresponding id.  I tried to do this in the success function, but my parameter-provided id value is not available there.

A slightly cleaned-up version of my code is below.  I'm not sure where to filter the response to only return the single item that corresponds with the variable id.

json.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class JsonService {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  getData(url): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .map(this.extractData);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

myComponent.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { JsonService } from '../../services/json.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mine',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  providers: [JsonService]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id:any;
  data:any;
  item:any;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _jsonService: JsonService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;  // console.log(this.id) reports the id as expected here
      let url = 'assets/data.json';
      this._jsonService.getData(url).subscribe(this.resSuccess, this.resFailure, this.resComplete);
    });
  }

  resSuccess(response) {
    this.data = response;
    this.data.data.forEach((obj)=>{
      if(obj.id == this.id){  // console.log(this.id) shows that this.id is undefined
        this.item = obj;
      }
    })
  }
  resFailure(error) {
    console.log("Error happened" + error);
  }
  resComplete() {
    console.log("the subscription is completed");
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

data.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "hurricane",
    "active": true,
    "title": "Forecast a Hurricane",
    "img": "/assets/hurricane.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "snow",
    "active": true,
    "title": "Create a Snowstorm",
    "img": "/assets/snow.jpg"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing free, unbound functions instead of methods that are bound to your object.

Use

```
this._jsonService.getData(url).subscribe(this.resSuccess.bind(this), this.resFailure.bind(this), this.resComplete.bind(this));
```

or

```
this._jsonService.getData(url).subscribe((res) => this.resSuccess(res), (err) => this.resFailure(err), () => this.resComplete());
```

Unbound function can't access `this`, because they do not belong to any object. Be careful with passing reference to function if you don't know how JS works.

Comment: This got me over my immediate hurdle.  Thank you.

Comment: @Avatarantella Consider upvoting / accepting answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipable operators for this. Something like this:

```
this._jsonService.getData(url).pipe(
    map(x => { 
        return x.filter(x => x.id === param.id) 
    }).subscribe();
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md